# How to set a breakpoint in an execve'd program in radare2?

Tags: debugging, x86, radare2, executable

If I have a program A, which uses `execve` to run program B. How can I set a breakpoint in program B's main routine if I'm debugging program A?

After a certain point in the execve routine, program B will be loaded into memory. After that I can see the symbols in the binary and the regions of memory they have been loaded into. However, to get to that point at the moment I just step through some of the execve instructions which is very fiddly and prone to mistakes.

Is there a simpler approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a debugging flag called `dbg.execs` that setting it to true should stop the execution when an `execv` is happening. So try this:

```
> e dbg.execs = true
```

It looks like it works on Linux, but I couldn't get the same behaviour on OSX.